# ASP.Net Response is empty if I don't add a space in front of output

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a weird problem and nothing is special.The output won't sent to browser till I add a space before the output. I've discovered the "workaround" while trying to make output = "test". What I do here is I just try to display html part of a mail message as webpage. If I copy the value of the variable "output" and save as .html file browser will display it. The problem here is no data sent to browser from iis express.

> **Update**: BIG CLUE: I got this problem at only one specific mail message (maybe others, either) and many messages have no problem. It
>   might be related to default output encoding UTF-8 vs non-utf8, I'm not
>   sure. The html part of message's character encoding is ISO-8859-9
>   (Turkish) but the output is ordinary *string* variable. I've converted string *output* to binary stream and examined the ascii numbers, there are no invisible bytes in string's binary value.

The code:

```
// output = " " + output;   // OK: Browser displays html page as expected
// output += " ";           // Not OK: No data at browser
// output = "test";         // OK: Browser displays text "test"
Response.Write(output);     // Without modification no data at browser
```

The debugger screen:

[image]

All browser headers seem like OK, I got a response but it's empty:

[image]

Response is empty when first char is not space:

[image]

Response is OK when I add a space as first char:

[image]

There is an unexpected newline instead of just a space at the beginning of source code of webpage:

[image]

Debugger Text Visualizer before modifying output:

[image]

Debugger Text Visualizer after modifying output:

[image]

**Question:** Why string output won't sent to browser here?

Comment: Could you add the response headers both for when it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: Why are you using Response.Write()?

Comment: @Xerillio I uncomment the line 332 and just hit F5, same headers sent to local server when I refresh the webpage

Comment: @NimeCloud Sounds like you're looking at **request headers** and not **response headers**. Please put those in your post. Also.. have you tried calling `Response.Flush()` after `Write()`?

Comment: @Xerillio: Response.Write(output) is not ok, Response.Write(" " + output) is OK. Why? I got this problem with only one mail message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following a topproach resolve your problem

You can use contentResult to do that... like

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Index() 
{
    return new ContentResult 
    {
        ContentType = "text/html",
        Content =@yourHtmlLink
    };
}
```

or

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent("<div>Hello World</div>");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: I already do that a line before the code: Response.ContentType = "text/html";
output = " " + output;
Response.Write(output);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();